# which code execute faster?

Tags: c

these are two codes

```
int d;
d=0;
d=a+b;
print d+c+e;
code 2:
print a+b+c+e;
```

I am trying c programming.
I am having some doubts in execution of this code
which code executes faster? and use less memory?

Comment: Your best bet is to look at the generated assembly, but chances are it's completely negligible both in terms of speed and memory usage (likely both will use registers and stack). You almost certainly have bigger problems to worry about in your program!

Comment: I think this program is not able to run itself.

Comment: Even if it was to be modified into 'real C' so as to run on a typical OS, the timing jitter on I/O, (never mind the I/O time itself), would exceed the time taken for a trivial bit of integer arithmetic, no matter how it was coded or compiled.

Comment: I can tell you which code fails to compile the quickest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you have posted,

**Example 1**

> ```
> int d;
> d=0;
> d=a+b;
> /* print d+c+e;*/
> printf("%i\n", d+c+e);
> ```

**Example 2**

> ```
> /* print a+b+c+e; */
> printf("%i\n", a+b+c+e);
> ```

Which is faster is tricky, if your compiler optimizes `d` away in *Example 1* they are equivalent. On the other hand, if your compiler can't determine that `d=0` is discarded (and it may not) then it can't decide that `d` is really `const int d = a+b;` and the examples will not be equivalent with *Example 2* being (slightly) faster.